# .NET Framework 4.7.1 Web API is serving outdated JSON schema to one client while serving newer JSON schema to other clients

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have an existing api that has one endpoint I want to update.

Currently it returns some oldData

```
{
    "oldData": "test" 
}
```

I added a new property to my API response and updated both my client and server-side code to be able to accept this new property.

```
{
    "oldData": "test" 
    "newProperty": "test2"
}
```

In order to test this API I have 3 tools at my disposal. Postman, Chrome, and a client library I made. The client library that uses HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() to get the json response. In earlier testing, all three tools yielded the same results.

When I call the endpoint in postman I get back JSON containing the new property. When I call the same endpoint in chrome I get back JSON containing the new property... So far, so good. However, When I call the same endpoint in my .Net console app, I get back JSON that does not match what the other two clients got. It does not contain the new property at all.

I thought it might just be caching the result somehow, so I changed the value of oldPoperty from "test" to "test2" and tested again in all 3 clients. The oldProperty appears updated in all 3 clients but still the console app does not get json containing the newProperty.

I tried a clean + rebuild + redeploy of the server-side code. I tried deleting the old server-side dlls and redeploying. I dried disabling authentication, I tried creating an entirely new console app. When running this in other environments, the console app works fine. It's as if and older version of the server-side code is handling responses from one client while the latest code is handling responses for the other two clients. I looked at fiddler as well and the only main difference is which cookies are set.

Comment: You might want to tag this with the server and framework you are using (and remove the [tag:api] tag which is marked DO NOT USE).  Your problem is likely specific to whatever version of each you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was related to Azure's WebAppTrafficRouting rules. I have a production slot and a "main" deployment slot. I want to use my main slot insead of the built-in production slot.

I use experimental AzWebAppTrafficRouting rules to route 100% of traffic to the main slot. This works just fine in browsers, but my API clients still hit the production slot unless I persist cookies send back from the server. When I persist cookies, only the first request hits the production slot and subsequent requests hit the main slot as desired. The only solve was to update the production slot with the latest code.

The cookie azure passes back to my api is named x-ms-routing-name  and it contains the routing rule name. Very strange behavior.